# Setting up a new iPad

Tags: ipad

iPad asks for my Apple ID and I entered my iCloud ID and password and it says that it is an incorrect Apple ID and password.

Comment: Is this a new iPad as in "newly bought from Apple" or as in "bought used from a friend or such"?

Answer (score 1):

If you are just activating it, it may be locked with someone else apple id.  it should show you the partial id.  if you bought it from a friend, you need to either have them remove it from the device by logging in and removing or you can turn it off and have them login to iCloud and remove it from their account.  here is a good link to check out:
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201365